# Chrome: Is possible to merge bookmarks data from two computers?

Tags: google-bookmarks, synchronization, chrome-bookmarks

I wonder how to merge bookmarks from two different computers into one Google account.
I have bookmarks in my laptop and bookmarks in the computer I use to work. Does anyone know how to put together into one Google account?

By the way,
I´ve just synchronized the bookmarks of my laptop with my Google account but I wonder what would happen next Monday when I will go to work and my Chrome synchronize with my Google account. That synchronization would erase the bookmarks I have in my office computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Chrome's sync, your bookmarks on the unsynced computer will be added to your network bookmarks.

I've done this before, and each time this is how it's worked.

Answer (score 3):

(If I remember right) you will be asked a question on what to do with the already existed bookmarks and one of the options is to merge them.

No matter what, Chrome is not going to delete anything valuable without your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

XMarks is the best bookmarks synchronizer, allows us to synchronize across different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE etc.).

Just make sure you turn off the browser's built-in bookmarks synchronization, else your bookmarks may be messed up.

Comment: It's totally different from what being asked here..